# How do i console.log something when a variable reach a certain value?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables

<!here's the html>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()"> 5 </button>

<button onclick="myFunction2()"> 7 </button>

<button onclick="myFunction3()"> +5 </button>



</body>


</html>
```

//The coding

```
var points = 0;

function myFunction() {

points = 5;

console.log(poeng)
}

function myFunction2() {

points = 7;

console.log(poeng)

}

function myFunction3() {

points = points + 5;

console.log(points)

}

if(points > 12) {

console.log("Hello World");

}
```

The program is based on this- you have three buttons. Button1 changes the variable "points" to 5, the second changes it to 7, and the third button plusses 5 on whatever value the variable has at the moment. The problem is that when you press the +5 button and get the variable value to be over 12 i want a message saying "Hello World". Sadly this does not work. Does anyone know what i can do? (It would be higly appreciated as this is for a school project).

Comment: I have removed the java tag as it's not related to the question.

Comment: your if statement is outside myfunction3, it needs to be inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve the same effect with functions with parameters:

```html
<button onclick="setPoints(5)"> 5 </button>

<button onclick="setPoints(7)"> 7 </button>

<button onclick="increasePoints(5)"> +5 </button>
```

```js
function setPoints(foo){
 points = foo;
}

function increasePoints(foo){
 points += foo;
 if(points>12){
  console.log("Hello World");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time doing this! It worked splendid! :)

Answer (score 0):

you're using plain js so the var point it's not reactive, the js files are reader from top to bottom and the if is readed at the same time, you should wrap the if in another funcion and emit it in all function

```
var points = 0;

function myFunction() {

points = 5;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function myFunction2() {

points = 7;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function myFunction3() {

points = points + 5;

console.log(points)
check()
}

function check() {
 if(points > 12) {

  console.log("Hello World");

 }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I am new to javascript so it is really nice that i have people like you to help! :)